# Bulk insert and update in one query sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite

is there any way to insert and update bulk data in same query. I have seen many likes but not getting solution. I get a code but its not working

```
INSERT INTO `demo1` (`id`,`uname`,`address`) 
 VALUES (1, 2, 3), 
 VALUES (6, 5, 4), 
 VALUES (7, 8, 9)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = VALUES(32), `uname` = VALUES (b),`address` = VALUES(c)
```

Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has the [REPLACE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html) (which is an alias for [INSERT OR REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)), but this just deletes the old row if a duplicate key is found.

If you want to keep data from the old row(s), you must use two statements for each row:

```python
db.execute("UPDATE demo1 SET ... WHERE id = 1")
if db.affected_rows == 0:
    db.execute("INSERT ...")
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, But how can I use it for bulk data. Can you please update your answer

Comment: I said "for each row".

Comment: So in that case i have to use loop system?